# On adding @EnableWebSecurity to the configuration class app is not running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, microservices

1. I have a spring-cloud-gateway to which I want to provide spring
   security so I have added spring-boot-starter-security till here  it
   worked absolutely as expected!!
2. Now I would want to add customauthentication and authorization using JPA for this I have added
   starter jpa and postgresql driver even it is worked fine.
3. The
   problem is when adding @EnableWebSecurity annotation when I add this
   to my security config class and run application is not running with
   below exception stack

**Tried cleaning and updating project , created new app from scratch to resolve any cache issues nothing worked **

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks in advance!! :)

Logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.uday.microservices.apigateway.ApiGatewayApplication.main(ApiGatewayApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 42 common frames omitted

2021-08-02 23:03:11.847  WARN 15632 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:886) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:874) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:802) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:348) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.uday.microservices.apigateway.ApiGatewayApplication.main(ApiGatewayApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.uday.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-cloud-gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Spring Boot Application Class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Security Configuration Class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;


@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigClass extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.configure(http);
    }

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SecurityConfigClass.configure()");
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }
    
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        
    }
    

}
```

Gateway configuration class

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;


@Configuration
public class ApiGatewayConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRouter(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path("/get")
                        .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("Myheader", "Myheader")
                        .addRequestParameter("param", "uday"))
                        .uri("http://httpbin.org:80"))
                .route(p -> p.path("/currency-exchange/**")
                        .uri("lb://currency-exchange"))
                .route(p -> p.path("/currency-conversion/**")
                        .uri("lb://currency-conversion"))
                .route(p -> p.path("/currency-conversion-feign/**")
                        .uri("lb://currency-conversion"))
                .route(p -> p.path("/currency-conversion-new/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath(
                                "/currency-conversion-new/(?<segment>.*)", 
                                "/currency-conversion-feign/${segment}"))
                        .uri("lb://currency-conversion"))
                .build();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You are mixing reactive and blocking features. Spring Cloud Gateway is based on webflux (reactive) and all your other dependencies are for blocking app. So you have to review your dependencies.

Comment: @akuma8 how to do that , can you please eloborate ...