# On Adding @EnableWebSecurity Spring Boot Application not starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am facing a similar problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68627399/on-adding-enablewebsecurity-to-the-configuration-class-app-is-not-running). Upon adding `@EnableWebSecurity` to my `SecurityConfiguration.java` class, the application fails to start. If I remove it, it starts with no error. Please, below is the error log.

```
2021-08-09 23:53:48.016 ERROR 1379 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at com.sg.sgbackend.SgbackendApplication.main(SgbackendApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@277050dc]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
        ... 37 common frames omitted

2021-08-09 23:53:48.045  WARN 1379 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@277050dc]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:886) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:874) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:802) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:348) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at com.sg.sgbackend.SgbackendApplication.main(SgbackendApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.sg'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    //implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    //implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Below is my Security Configuration Class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
     @Override
     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user")).roles("USER");
     }

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

What am I mixing?
Please, I need help to fix this issue.

Comment: What has your research told you is the usual cause of a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`?

Comment: I have added the javax dependency that is supposed to have the javax.servlet.Filter class but the issue still persists.
`dependencies {...
 compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
 runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
 testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
 testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
 testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
 testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}`

Comment: no one can help you by just posting a stack trace. Please put some effort into your question. ClassNotFoundExceptions are 99% due to bad dependencies, so please post your poms and your FULL debug log. Voted to close, lacking debugging details.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I have improved the question, any help?

Comment: Please try removing `compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'` in your `build.gradle` or replacing `compileOnly` with `implementation`. Then `javax.servlet.Filter` should also be available at runtime.

Comment: @Henning, thank you for the suggested change. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Henning, I affected the change in the build.gradle file by replacing compileOnly to implementation for the javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.sg'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    //implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    //implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And add

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

To the application.properties file.